# RaspberryPi4/Windows10 doesn't recognizes USB devices after boot

Tags: boot, pi-4, boot-issues, windows

I've installed Windows 10 on my Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB) with this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0_kEV-gdtI). That worked but when Windows started and wanted to run the setup, it no longer recognized my keyboard and mouse. So I can't make any entries. (Keyboard works in boot menu.)

So I looked at what could be wrong and found that USB could be disabled. -> [Legacy USB Support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZKRc2LoY3c)

Knowing this, I searched the boot menu of my RaspberryPi4 / Windows10 but couldn't find a function that activate USB. So now i stuck on the Windows startup page and can't do anything.

The boot menu looks like this:

```
Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
BCM2711 (ARM Cortex-A72)                                  1.50 GHz
UEFI Firmware v1.17                                       4096 MB RAM


    Select Language               <Standart English>

> Device Manager
> Boot Manager
> Boot Maintenance Manager 

  Continue
  Reset
```

How can I activate my keyboard and mouse?

Comment: the tutorial tells you right at the beginning that USB ports do not work on the Pi4

Comment: But how to control the RPi4 when usb doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial states you cannot use the USB ports and wifi on the pi 4. If you want to use windows on it you would have to buy a type C to type A converter that would look like this:

[image: A picture of the cable I described above]

You could then use a USB hub to connect multiple USB devices. You would then have to supply power through the GPIO Pins.

Here's what the person in the tutorial did:

[image: Image from the tutorial 1]

[image: Image from the tutorial 2]